# What Perl matching regexp nuances can cause headaches?

Tags: regex, perl

This code failed to identify any of the keys it appears to identify:

```
if( $key =~ /upsf|free|ground|sla|pickup|usps/ )
```

So I changed it to :

```
    if( $key eq 'upsf' || $key eq 'free' 
    || $key eq 'ground' || $key eq 'sla' 
    || $key eq 'pickup' || $key eq 'usps' )
```

<strike>They look to me like they are functionally equivalent</strike>, so I'm trying to figure out why the first one failed.  It's Perl under XAMPP on Windows 7, but it's also Perl under Apache2 on a Linux box.

This prints "shelf it" - both on Windows and Linux.

```
$key = 'upsf';
if( $key =~ /^(upsf|free|ground|sla|pickup|usps)$/ ) {
    print 'ship it';
} else {
    print 'shelf it';
}
```

Comment: What text are you matching? What is the value of `$key`? Your second line is actually equal to `/^(upsf|free|ground|sla|pickup|usps$)/`, not `/upsf|free|ground|sla|pickup|usps/`.

Comment: it should work, perhaps you are missing something else?

Comment: Your question is moot. The code presented should work, given suitable input. Give us a short, self-contained and correct example (including input) that demonstrates your problem. I think you will find, in this case, that your problem is with your input.

Comment: hah, weird solution: `$c = 'free';
print index(join("|",qw(upsf free ground sla pickup usps)), $c);`

Comment: Note my edit, since simbabque was right (though loldop is right too).  perreal, did you try the code in Perl?  I think loldop did, but I can't tell.  Reproduction of this strange failure would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

They're not equiv, as the comparison operator in the first is "=~" ("contains"),
where in the second it is "eq" ("explicit match, equals").

How exactly did the first one fail? What was your test value for $key?

```
$key = 'xxx';
if( $key =~ /upsf|free|ground|sla|pickup|usps/ ) {
    print 'ship it';
} else {
    print 'shelf it';
}
```

will print 'shelf it'.
  Whereas $key='xusps' , for example, will print 'ship it', match via '=~' operator ("contains"), which may not be your goal.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
if ($key =~ /^(?:upsf|free|ground|sla|pickup|usps)$/) {
  # ...
} else {
  # ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## My Bad!

This code is executed by ClickCart Pro, which reads it from a file and preprocesses it like this:

```
$custom_script_code =~ s/\`/\'/gs;
$custom_script_code =~ s/\|\|/%7C%7C/g;
$custom_script_code =~ s/\|/ /gs;
$custom_script_code =~ s/%7C%7C/\|\|/g;
$custom_script_code =~ s/system/System/gs;
$custom_script_code =~ s/exec/Exec/gs;
$custom_script_code =~ s/die/Die/gs;
```

So the pipes are removed by the third statement here.  Thanks Kryptronics! (sarcasm)  perreal's comment has been plussed.  I shouldn't get any points for this.  Sorry I wasted everyone's time!